# does numpy asarray() refer to original list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very long list of list and I am converting it to a numpy array using numpy.asarray(), is it safe to delete the original list after getting this matrix or does the newly created numpy array will also be affected by this action?

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that data is not shared and that you can safely remove the lists. Your original `matrix` is a nested structure of Python objects, with the numbers itself also Python objects, which can be located everywhere in memory. A Numpy array is also an object, but it is more or less a header that contains the dimensions and type of the data, with a pointer to a contiguous block of data where all the numbers are packed as close as possible as 'raw numbers'. There is no way how these two different ways could share data, so presumably the data is copied when you create the Numpy array. Example:

```
In [1]: m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: M = np.array(m)
In [4]: M[1,1] = 55
In [5]: M
Out[5]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 55,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
In [6]: m
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] # original is not modified!
```

Note that Numpy arrays **can** share data between each other, e.g. when you make a slice into an array. This is called a 'view', so if you modify data in the subset, it will also change in the original array:

```
In [18]: P = M[1:, 1:]
In [19]: P[1,1] = 666
In [20]: P
Out[20]: 
array([[ 55,   6],
       [  8, 666]])
In [21]: M
Out[21]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [  4,  55,   6],
       [  7,   8, 666]])  # original is also modified!
```

Comment: A NumPy array and list can surely share data, at least when the dtype is object: `d = [[1, 2, 'foo'], ['12', 13]]; np.asarray(d)[0] is d[0] --> True`. Now changing the items in inner list will affect the array items as well. But the point is deletion of that list(unless the deletion is delslice applied on inner lists) won't affect the array at all, because deletion simply results in 
decrease in refcount.

Comment: I assumed we were talking about numbers, but yes, when dtype is object, the objects in the matrix stay the same. But you can still safely delete the lists, I guess, since the objects are then held alive by the Numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

The data are copied over because the numpy array stores its own copy of the data as described by Bas Swinckels. You can test this for your self too.  Although the trivially small list might make the point too, the ginormous data set below might bring the point home a little better ;)

```
import numpy as np
list_data = range(1000000000)   # note, this will probably take a long time

# This will also take a long time 
# because it is copying the data in memory
array_data = np.asarray(list_data) 

# even this will probably take a while
del list_data

# But you still have the data even after deleting the list
print(array_data[1000])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually tried this and somehow in one of the run, the numpy array was getting affected but i could never reproduce the scenario, so perhaps some mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to delete it if your input data consists of a `list`. From the documentation `No copy is performed (ONLY) if the input is already an ndarray.`